# With PHP preg_match_all, get value of href

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I don'T really understabd how regular expressions works even after I read this tutorial http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php

Here is what I need to find:

```
<link type="text/html" rel="alternate" href="http://link"/>
```

And it should return:

```
http://link
```

Here is what I tried:

```
$find = preg_match_all(
    '/<link type="text/html" rel="alternate" href=".*',
    $file,
    $patterns2
);
```

You can laught :)

Thanks in advance for your help and your time :)

Comment: Are you sure, you didn't get an error message somewhere about a missing delimiter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using simplexml

```
$html = '<link type="text/html" rel="alternate" href="http://link"/>';
$xml  = simplexml_load_string($html);
$attr = $xml->attributes();
```

using dom

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('link');
$attr  = $nodes->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
```

Comment: I think i'll use DOM, which one do you prefer? (I just listen o your youtube videoand i love that :))

Comment: @Jeremy Dicaire - `DOMDocument::loadHTML` will fix the malformed html for you, so is preferred. But simple meant simple (I personally prefer simplexml if the html is not malformed)

Answer (score 3):

Parsing (X)HTML with regex is [almost certainly wrong](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html). Use a dedicated XML parser. There are plenty available for php.

Comment: Thanks I just read the article, interresting and useful... I'll not do the same mistake in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to cover the needed text-chunk in brackets like `(.*)`, that is what will be returned

This one is working for me

```
<?php
preg_match_all('/<link type="text\/html" rel="alternate" href="(.*)"\/>/','<link type="text/html" rel="alternate" href="http://link"/>',$patterns2);
print_r($patterns2);
?>
```

Comment: Why are you getting into that? You were supposed to tell him to *not* parse HTML using regexes. Also, `<link <link foo href=".."` matches your regex. See what I mean?

Comment: I'm sorry that i've gave him what he wanted.

Comment: if it solved your problem, mark it like solved (green nike symbol) ;)

Comment: You gave him broken code that appeared to give him what he wanted, but was buggy and inextensible, as pointed out by Mr goreSplatter.