# How do I obtain the canonical value using PHP DomDocument?

Tags: php, dom

```
<link rel='canonical' href='http://test.com/asdfsdf/sdf/' />
```

I need to get the canonical href value using Dom. How do I do this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.

Using XML:

```
<?php

$html = "<link rel='canonical' href='http://test.com/asdfsdf/sdf/' />";

$xml  = simplexml_load_string($html);
$attr = $xml->attributes();
print_r($attr);

?>
```

which outputs:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [rel] => canonical
            [href] => http://test.com/asdfsdf/sdf/
        )

)
```

or, using Dom:

```
<?php

$html = "<link rel='canonical' href='http://test.com/asdfsdf/sdf/' />";

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('link');
foreach ($nodes as $node)
{
    if ($node->getAttribute('rel') === 'canonical')
    {
        echo($node->getAttribute('href'));
    }
}

?>
```

which outputs:

```
http://test.com/asdfsdf/sdf/
```

In both examples, more code is required if you're parsing an entire HTML file, but they demonstrate most of the structure that you'll need.

Code modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4587441/869912) and [the documentation on Dom](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Comment: `foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('link') as $item)
  {
   if ($item->getAttribute('rel') === 'canonical') {
    echo $item->getAttribute('href');
   }
  }`

Comment: Looks like you've got it. I tweaked your code a bit and updated my answer too.

Comment: Using XPath
```php
$xpath->query('//link[contains(@rel,"canonical")]/@href');
if($nodeList->length > 0) $canonical_url = $nodeList->item($i)->value;
```