# Regex for b, i and a tags only or none in a string

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to know the possible Regex  suitable for checking a string that includes certain HTML tags, namely, `<b>`, `<i>` and `<a>` or it has no any tags. using PHP preg_match.

For example:

```
"This a text only.." return true
"This is a <b>bold</b> text" return true
"this is <script>alert('hi')</script>" return false
"this is <a href="#">some</a>and <h1>header</h1>" return false
```

Comment: [It's not a good idea to parse HTML using regular expressions...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/869912)

Comment: Not only is this a bad idea, but you show no evidence of attempting to find a solution yourself.

Comment: @RicardoAltamirano What's the best idea?!

Comment: @user1592845 You could parse the HTML document using either XML or Dom, as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11383144/869912).

Comment: @SomeKittens It is just a comments form and I'd like to ensure that user's input does not has any tags else those three tags!

Comment: @user1592845 actually, it's not.  This is a Question and Answer site.  If you'd taken the 60 seconds it takes to read the relevant FAQ, you'd have known that.  We won't do your work for you.

Comment: @SomeKittens  Ok, Thank you, but I still think that it is a question. Otherwise, this website should not have a commenting feature!

Comment: It's not a real question, just you begging for us to write your code.

Comment: @SomeKittens There is only one evidence replies to your talk, I accepted an answer has no relation with Regex. In addition I gained one extra useful piece of information that parsing HTML with Regex is not suitable idea!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) instead.  Regular expressions aren't suited for parsing HTML tags.

```
var_dump(isTextClean('This a text only..')); // true
var_dump(isTextClean('This is a <b>bold</b> text')); // true
var_dump(isTextClean('this is <script>alert(\'hi\')</script>')); // false
var_dump(isTextClean('this is <a href="#">some</a>and <h1>header</h1>')); // false

function isTextClean($input) {
    $result = strip_tags($input, '<b><i><a>');

    if ($result != $input) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it solves my little problem!

Comment: I would condense the function body to `return strip_tags($input, '<b><i><a>') == $input`.